# CI/CD for ASP.NET big size application

Tags: c#, asp.net, git, continuous-integration

I am working on an old asp.net 4.0 webform application.
There are various modules in the application and their pages (code) are arranged in subdirectories created by the name of the module.
Unfortunately the user documents are also uploaded to these subdirectories and hence making the application size 50-60 gB now and it is increasing day by day.

Also, there is no version control and hence there are issues and challenges in code merge and manual deployment to production for any change.
So, I want to implement CI/CD for this application.
Is it a good idea to use GIT for this type of application architecture and how to achieve this?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Git is the most popular version control system. There shouldn't be any issues with using this for your project's version control (I assume the 50-60GB of user data is separate to your code).

Comment: User docs are not separately stored. Within a module there may be more than one directories that contain user data.

Comment: I'd probably look into changing that if I were you.

Comment: Git itself is not a CI/CD system: it's just a Source Code Management system (SCM) or Version Control System (VCS). Many CI/CD systems are built to *use* Git though. You should read up on version control in general, Git specifically, and CI/CD in general, and decide whether any particular CI/CD system fits your needs and see if it requires or encourages Git as "the" VCS and if so whether Git fits your needs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using git for version control and CI/CD using Azure DevOps or similar should work fine, but for this to work efficiently you should address the main problems that (other that not using version control, IMO) you have: mixing user data and code deployment.

You should move out all user generated data (here: user documents) from the site deployment. Not doing this will make the CD (deployment) part very challenging. Create an abstraction layer of some sort for uploading and downloading user documents so that you can store that data somewhere else, like blob storage, shared disk or even in a database (not good, but better than inside your deployment).

Without doing this, you will have a hard time doing proper CI/CD with all the benifits that it will bring.

As a side effect, this will also bring other benifits:

1. It will be possible to scale your application to multiple working processes.
2. It will be possible way easier to spin up new environments with data copied from another environment (e.g. you can easily make a staging environment with data copied from production).